# showing data from 2 views using pouchdb

Tags: angular, error-handling, controller, couchdb, pouchdb

I need help for my problem. I get the remarks view. but arrears is not displayed. I don't know why this happen. I have 2 views using pouchdb. now i want to show 2 views using 1 list.

controller:

```
angular.module('app').
```

controller('AuditReportController', ['$q','Database', 'Remarks', '$routeParams',
    function($q, Database, Remarks,$routeParams)
    {
        var that = this;

```
    this.remarks = [];
    this.load = function(arrear_id, startkey)
    {
        var remark = null;
        Remarks.all($routeParams.arrear_id, 100, startkey).
            then(function(response) {
                return response.rows.map(function(row) { return row.doc; });
            }).
            then(function(remarks) {
                remark = remarks;
                var promises = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < remarks.length; i++) {
                    //promises.push();
                    promises.push(Database.get(remark[i].arrear_id));
                }
                return $q.all(promises);
            })
            .then(function(arrears) {
                for (var i = 0; i < arrears.length; i++) {
                    remark[i].arrear = arrears[i];
                }
                that.remarks = that.remarks.concat(remark);
            });
    };
    this.load();
```

I think my controller have error code or my promise not correct, i don't know why this happen.

html5:

```
<div id="printDev">
                <table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="row-border hover  md-caption">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{ 'title_bil' | translate }}</th>
                        <th>{{ 'title_username' | translate }}</th>
                        <th>{{ 'title_owner_name' | translate }}</th>
                        <th>{{ 'title_account_id' | translate }}</th>
                        <th>{{ 'title_recipient_name' | translate }}</th>
                        <th>{{ 'title_recipient_id' | translate }}</th>
                        <th>{{ 'title_time' | translate }}</th>
                        <th>{{ 'title_note' | translate }}</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="remark in data = (controller.remarks | filter:query:regex | orderBy:'created_at':reverse)">
                        <td>{{ $index + 1 }}.</td>
                        <td>{{ remark.username}}</td>
                        <td>{{ arrears.owner_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ arrears.account_id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ remark.recipient_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{ remark.recipient_id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ remark.created_at | date:'dd/MM/yyyy H:m a'}}</td>
                        <td>{{ remark.note}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

error:

```
:5984/arrears_database/f54f91975c66a07d399c14e03701a1b6? Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
```

Comment: If you want to add a v alue to an array in Javascript, you have to use [.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/push), not **add**. Line : promises.add()

Comment: I already using push(), and i get the data. but the data i get like this **GET http://192.168.1.55:5984/arrears_database/f54f91975c66a07d399c14e03701a1b6? net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES**. I don't know why this happen.

Comment: This is related to memory allocation. Basically, your request is requires too much memory. Is it possible that you are request too much data for your client?

Comment: ok, so now what must i do for get the data.

Comment: Well, what is you request? Are you requesting all the documents of one database?

Comment: yes, i think this problem because my ram computer cannot get all the document. that's why the message return error. now i set limit and startkey for solve my ram problem but still cannot load all data.

Comment: Ok so, if you do the same request directly to CouchDB, do you have the same error? Also, you should not have to get all the remote database documents. Consider implementing paging and query data only when needed